# STL Sort use of Static Function

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am trying to make it so that my enemies in my game are sorted in a vector in order of distance from the player and so I am using the sort function. Obviously, my enemies are objects so the basic predicate isn't enough and I have to make my own function, so I did.

However, these functions have to be static, and so, how, in this function, can I compare the distance between the enemy and the player?

```
double World::getPlayerDistance(Entity* enemy){

int xDistance = enemy->m_xValue - m_pPlayer->m_xValue;
int yDistance = enemy->m_yValue - m_pPlayer->m_yValue;

double dist = sqrt(pow((double)xDistance, 2) + pow((double)yDistance, 2));

return dist;
}
```

This is the code I'm trying to use, but as it is a static function (defined static in the header) it doesn't have access to member variables and so the following doesn't work:

```
bool World::sortXDistance(Entity *i, Entity *j) { 
return (getPlayerDistance(i) < getPlayerDistance(j)); 
}
```

(Also defined static in header) This is for use with the STL sorting with a Vector.

I have tried googling around, but perhps I don't even recognise the true problem, so any help would be appreciated, or an alternate way of doing it would be considered. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: So make it a class-static member fn? or better still, a class-level-functor which will likely inline. Or maybe make World a friend of Enemy?(and those raw pointers in that vector should be scary).

Comment: Would you mind explaining a little more in-depth? :) I'll be back on tomorrow, (I've spent too long on this already) but  I'll definitely look into this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a functor with a reference to a World object as a member, like this one:

```
struct CloserToPlayer
{
    World const & world_;
    CloserToPlayer(World const & world) :world_(world) {}

    bool operator()(Entity const * lhs, Entity const * rhs) const
    {
        return world_.getPlayerDistance(lhs) < world_.getPlayerDistance(rhs);
    }
};

...
World theWorld;
std::vector<Entity*> entities;
...
std::sort(entities.begin(), entities.end(), CloserToPlayer(theWorld));
```

Or, with C++11 lambdas:

```
auto CloserToPlayer = [&](Entity const * lhs, Entity const * rhs) {
        return theWorld.getPlayerDistance(lhs) < theWorld.getPlayerDistance(rhs);
    };
std::sort(entities.begin(), entities.end(), CloserToPlayer);
```

Comment: Will this work even if I'm inside the World Class? :) This looks good and I'll be trying this in a while but I just wanted to further my understanding etc :)

Comment: Sorry to bump this again, I am trying to call this from within the world class, I am trying several things out but I'm not sure what's going wrong, exactly. If push coes to shove, I suppose I could move all the stuff here to the class that has world objects in it. Please advise!

Comment: @BradleyHodgkins: By "inside the World class", do you mean "from inside of a member function of the World class"?  If so, then yes, it should.  You just need to pass `*this` as the argument to the constructor of the  `CloserToPlayer` functor.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry that this didn't work for me, I did try to work it through, but I worked out a different way of achieving my goal. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own problem. Instead of trying to access a non-static member function inside a static function, I did the player distance check outside of this, and assigned the result to the entities/enemies. This way, when I call sortXDistance, I just did:

```
bool World::sortXDistance(Entity *i, Entity *j){
    return (i->m_playerDistance < j->m_playerDistance);
}
```

Thank for your help, I did try your ways out but just kept getting errors I didn't understand :) My way is here at least for reference if anyone ever has this problem and wants my terrible way, and I'll give you the answer for the most likely better way of doing it.